# Getting Visual Studio Code to compile and run CPP Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I downloaded Microsoft Visual Studio Code
I added the C/C++ extension.

I'm following the instructions given by Microsoft verbatim, but it is not working.

Could somebody who is familiar with this application be my Sherpa in setting up VSC to run C/C++ code via git 4 windows/ mingw64.

This is nonspecific, however a back and forth dialog would probably be more effective given the circumstance.  Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What isn't working exactly? What errors are you getting? What are you expecting to happen? What directions are you following? A link would help. Please edit your question with the answers and not add them as a comment.

Comment: You don’t need mingw64 if you have VS.  Stack Exchange is not a forum, so back and forth dialogues, are not allowed.  Your question as it’s currently written is not clear